# extract a subset of a collection in MongoDB and save as a new collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, subset

I have a big MongoDB collection named `ebola`. I need to extract a subset of its first 1000 documents and save them into a new collection called `sample`. The code should be something like this:

```
db.createCollection("sample")  
db.sample.insert(db.ebola.find({}).limit(1000))
```

But what is wrong with it?

Comment: my bad! I edited the topic

Comment: Oh sorry. in fact I am new with MongoDB  and I want to get a subset from my collection  which is too big and save that subset into a new collection in dat mongoDB database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a subset of MongoDB(3.0) collection to another collection in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959206/save-a-subset-of-mongodb3-0-collection-to-another-collection-in-python) (I realise this question was asked first, but the other almost identical question has an answer)