# Save a subset of MongoDB(3.0) collection to another collection in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I found this answer - [Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247084/609782)

```
db.full_set.aggregate([ { $match: { date: "20120105" } }, { $out: "subset" } ]);
```

I want do same thing but with first 15000 documents in collection, I couldn't find how to apply limit to such query (I tried using `$limit : 15000`, but it doesn't recognize $limit)

also when I tried -

```
db.subset.insert(db.full_set.find({}).limit(15000).toArray())
```

there is no function `toArray()` for output type `cursor`.

Guide me how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Did you try `db.full_set.aggregate([ { $match: { date: "20120105" } }, { $limit : 15000 }, { $out: "subset" } ]);`?

Comment: I am running this in Jupyter notebook, it says "$" is not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
in python, this is how things work - `$limit` needs to be wrapped in `""`,
and you need to create a pipeline to execute it as a command.

In my code -

```
    pipeline = [{ '$limit': 15000 },{'$out': "destination_collection"}]
    db.command('aggregate', "source_collection", pipeline=pipeline)
```

You need to wrap everything in double quotes, including your source and destination collection.
And in `db.command` db is the object of your database (ie dbclient.database_name)

As per this answer -

> It works about 100 times faster than forEach at least in my case. This is because the entire aggregation pipeline runs in the mongod process, whereas a solution based on find() and insert() has to send all of the documents from the server to the client and then back. This has a performance penalty, even if the server and client are on the same machine.

The one that really helped me figure this answer out - [Reference 1](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/06/using-mongodbs-new-aggregation.html)

And [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/aggregation/)